# Can I switch use of 'entities.SingleOrDefault' ==> 'entities.Find' without hazards?

Tags: entities, dbcontext

In my WCF service's business logic, most of the places when I need to locate an entity, I use this syntax:

```
public void UpdateUser(Guid userId, String notes)
{
    using (ProjEntities entities = new ProjEntities())
    {
          User currUser = entities.SingleOrDefault(us => us.Id == userId);
          if (currUser == null)
               throw new Exception("User with ID " + userId + " was not found");
    }
}
```

I have recentely discovered that the `DbContext` has the `Find` method, and I understand I can now do this:

```
public void UpdateUser(Guid userId, String notes)
{
    using (ProjEntities entities = new ProjEntities())
    {
          User currUser = entities.Find(userId);
          if (currUser == null)
               throw new Exception("User with ID " + userId + " was not found");
    }
}
```

Note : the 'userId' property is the primary key for the table.

I read that when using `Find` method entity framework checks first to see if the entity is already in the local memory, and if so - brings it from there. Otherwise - a trip is made to the database (vs. `SingleOrDefault` which always makes a trip to the database).

I was wondering if I now will convert all my uses of `SingleOrDefault` to `Find` is there any potential of danger?

Is there a chance I could get some old data that has not been updated if I use `Find` and it fetches the data from memory instead of the database?

What happens if I have the user in memory, and someone changed the user in the database - won't it be a problem if I always use now this 'memory' replica instead of **always** fetching the latest updated one from the database?

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a chance I could get some old data that has not been updated
>   if I use Find and it fetches the data from memory instead of the
>   database?*

I think you have sort of answered your own question here. Yes, there is a chance that using `Find` you could end up having an entity returned that is out of sync with your database because your context has a local copy.

There isn't much more anyone can tell you without knowing more about your specific application; do you keep a context alive for a long time or do you open it, do your updates and close it? obviously, the longer you keep your context around the more susceptible you are to retrieving an up to date entity.

I can think of two strategies for dealing with this. The first is outlined above; open your context, do what you need and then dispose of it:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var entity = ctx.EntitySet.Find(123);
    // Do something with your entity here...
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Secondly, you could retrieve the [DbEntityEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for your entity and use the `GetDatabaseValues` method to update it with the values from the database. Something like this:

```
var entity = ctx.EntitySet.Find(123);

// This could be a cached version so ensure it is up to date.
var entry = ctx.Entry(entity);
entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(entry.GetDatabaseValues());
```